# uso de la libreria pattern python

Tags: python, regex, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

estoy en la realizacion de proyecto de NLTK, y deseo llevar las palabras a su verbo, he leido algo de la libreria pattern pero no encuentro ejemplos muy claros de como utilizarlo, agradeceria que me ayudaran con uno o dos ejemplos. por ejemplo si tengo la palabra "corriendo", que me devuelva "correr"

Comment: Deberías ser más específico. No sé si quieres hacer algo con la librería NLTK o si estás buscando otra librería. Lo que pides son comparaciones difusas (_fuzzy_) para lo que hay varios módulos como [fuzzywuzzy](https://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/). Concreta más con un ejemplo claro qué es lo que quieres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

te dejo un ejemplo que acabo de probar:

```
from pattern.es import conjugate, INFINITIVE
print conjugate('corriendo', INFINITIVE)
# Te devuelve "correr"
```

Toda la documentación la obtuve de: [Documentación](https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/pattern-es)

Dicha documentación tiene una tabla de ejemplo bastante grande de todas las conjugaciones y como transformar cualquier palabra a la conjugación que elijas.

Saludos